# Convert Vector to String?

Tags: java, vector

I have a problem, when I am  converting **vector to String**.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync.dataToDB(Package_sync.java:98)
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync.<init>(Package_sync.java:29)
    at Package_Sync.Package_sync$3.run(Package_sync.java:319)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<vectron1.size();i++){

    Vector temp = new Vector();
    temp.add(vectron1.get(i));

    for(int j=0;j<temp.size();j++){

        String sql = "insert into t_pkg_details(pkgname,classname)   values(?,?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        String name = (String) temp.get(0);
        String value = (String) temp.get(1);

        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,value);
        ps.execute();

        System.out.println("Extra class Inserted Successfully!");
    }
}
```

Can any one tell me, what is wrong in my code?.

(Note: The Same type of logic can accept in my another project, but here it throws an exception).

Comment: First of all, what is `vectron1`?  It would help to see how it's declared.  Second, why are you trying to get two elements out of `temp`, when you only put one into it?

Comment: Also, if at all possible, please don't use raw generic types like `Vector`; it is much better to specify what kind of object you expect to be in the vector, i.e. `Vector<String>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go for this,

```
    String name = String.valueOf(temp.get(0));
    String value =  String.valueOf(temp.get(1));
```

in case of **Object.toString()**, if the instance is null, a **NullPointerException** will be thrown, so, arguably, it's less safe.Whereas, using **String.valueOf()** you may not check for null.

as  [**ajb suggested**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907582/convert-vector-to-string#comment49853442_30907642)  you can handle **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** by wrapping your code in if else

```
if (temp.size <= Your Max Index){
//your Code
}
else{
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

and for information The **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** is a sub-class of the **IndexOutOfBoundsException**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String name = (String) temp.get(0);
 String value = (String) temp.get(1);
```

I think, that you cant do this, you're trying to cast a string to Vector, that's the reason of `java.lang.ClassCastException` . Here is an example:

```
Vector vec1 = new Vector();
String str1 = vec1.toString();
```

Now in this example I'm casting a vector to string, so it's a valid compilation.